# Symfony parameter yml configuration for paths into a specific bundle

Tags: php, twig, yaml, symfony

I have declared a controller as service and want to pass the template path to be rendered by the twig engine as a parameter.

The twig template file is in the same Bundle of the controller, and I'm defining it in the same service.yml file.

Given that the template is under *MyBundle\Resources\views\my\path\templatename.html.twig* how can I reference to it in the yml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

```
parameters:
    templatePath: 'MyBundle:my/path/filename.html.twig'
```